# Hover to change image is not working in Angular4

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I am working in an Angula4 project ,In this I have a hover to change image section ,I have did something like the below code but it is not working for me ,But the same code is perfectly working in (visual studio)other project.

[image]

What should I do next or What I have missed in this ...

product.component.html

```
<div class="col-5">
      <div class="container" >
        <img src="assets/bank/cart.png" id="ProductImage" class="img-fluid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
        <div class="12">
        <div class="row">
          <img id="sm001" src="assets/bank/bal1.jpg" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" ref="assets/Product_Details/Show1.png">
          <img id="sm005" src="assets/bank/bal2.jpg" alt="img2" class="img-thumbnail" ref="assets/Product_Details/Show2.png">
          <img id="sm002" src="assets/bank/bal3.jpg" alt="img3" class="img-thumbnail" ref="assets/Product_Details/Show3.png">
          <img id="sm003" src="assets/bank/bal4.jpg" alt="img4" class="img-thumbnail" ref="assets/Product_Details/Show4.png">
          <img id="sm004" src="assets/bank/bal5.jpg" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" ref="assets/Product_Details/Show5.png">
      </div>
    </div>
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">`</script>
    <script>
      $('img[id^=sm00]').click(function () {
          $('#ProductImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('ref'));
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: why are u using jquery..same can be done in angular

Comment: use `(mouseenter) ="mouseEnter() "` event to your image tag

Comment: I keep the <script></script> in index.html Which is in Angular4 project.

Comment: no need to do so..i shall create stackblitz to solve ur issue

Comment: we don't recommend usage of jquery in angular application'

Comment: So ,How can I achieve this in Angular4 project

Comment: chk my answer updated below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below :

product.component.html

```
<div class="col-5">
      <div class="container" >
        <img [src]="imageURL" id="ProductImage" class="img-fluid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
        <div class="12">
        <div class="row">
          <img id="sm001" (click)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" ref="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
          <img id="sm005" (click)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/351x151" alt="img2" class="img-thumbnail" ref="https://via.placeholder.com/351x151">
          <img id="sm002" (click)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/352x152" alt="img3" class="img-thumbnail" ref="https://via.placeholder.com/352x152">
          <img id="sm003" (click)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/353x153" alt="img4" class="img-thumbnail" ref="https://via.placeholder.com/353x153">
          <img id="sm004" (click)="mouseEnter($event)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave($event)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/354x154" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" ref="https://via.placeholder.com/354x154">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Please replace placeholder images with your images.

product.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './product.component.css' ]
})
export class ProductComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  imageURL:string ;

  constructor(){

  }

  mouseEnter(event){
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.ref;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
    console.log(value)
    this.imageURL = value ; //I have binded thisvariable in HTML
  }

  mouseLeave(ev){
    //reset this.imageURL if needed
  }
}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-s8dncx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Updated code with click event handler

**UPDATE**

To show default image change your .ts file to :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './product.component.css' ]
})
export class ProductComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
   imageURL:string = "https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"; // change is here

  constructor(){

  }

  mouseEnter(event){
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.ref;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
    console.log(value)
    this.imageURL = value ; //I have binded thisvariable in HTML
  }

  mouseLeave(ev){
    //reset this.imageURL if needed
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-s8dncx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: by default want to show an image at the big box...but if I gave [src]="imageURL" this I can't set the another image source...

Comment: Can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748925/adding-products-in-cart-carousel-generate-new-row-of-slider-in-angular4